# How to authorize API endpoint through header using wp_remote_get()?

Tags: php, wordpress, xmlhttprequest, http-headers

I am testing API Football on my WP site and facing a difficulty in authentication. I have tested endpoint on postman and everything works fine but as soon as I test it on WP it gives me following response with error:

`{ "get": "status", "parameters": [], "errors": { "token": "Error/Missing application key. Go to https://www.api-football.com/documentation-v3 to learn how to get your API application key." }, "results": 0, "paging": { "current": 1, "total": 1 }, "response": [] }`

My WP code is:

```
    $response   = wp_remote_get( 'https://v3.football.api-sports.io/status', array(
        'headers'   => array(
            'x-apisports-key'   => $this->api_key
        )
    ) );

    $response_body  = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );

    return json_decode( $response_body );
```

I have tried php curl too but still getting same problem. For some reason I don't want to try it on rapidapi.

I have tried php cURL too but still getting same error. For some reasons I don't want to use rapidapi.

Comment: I think you are passing the header data in the wrong structure. The documentation refers to `WP_Http::request` for an explanation of the argument, and the coding of that uses `WP_Http::processHeaders` - and the documentation for the latter says, _"If an array is passed, then it is assumed to be raw header data with numeric keys with the headers as the values."_ So you should pass `array('x-apisports-key: ' . $this->api_key)`

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for response but authorization still not working with raw header.

Comment: Then you need to figure out where the significant difference between your working request in Postman, and your attempt(s) is. You say you could not manage to get it done using cURL either - not even when you let Postman create the PHP cURL code for you, based on your working request?

Comment: @CBroe Thanks mate, I generated cURL snippet form postman and it works. Now I can compare my code with it to know what might have gone wrong.